# The on-topic of this site needs to be changed. What should it be?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, scope

I just noticed that the on-topic of this site does "not work" (it is currently the site's name, Mathematics Educators, but this is does not really fit for our name).

The problem can, for example, be seen in [the tour](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tour) [my emphasis]

> Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those involved in the field of teaching mathematics. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about **mathematics educators.**

and the box on [the ask page](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) [my emphasis]

> How to Ask
>
> Is your question about **mathematics educators**?
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

The question to be decided is: What should the on-topic say?

Remarks

1. Whatever you suggest please make sure it works in the phrases I mentioned above in place of "mathematics educators" (it is my understanding that each site has "title", "on-topic", "target audience" and these get used at various places on and off the site, so there is not much flexibility).
2. In some sense, we had a lot of dicussion and even a vote on this already as most proposals for the name we had would have worked; see https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13356/vote-here-to-decide-the-name
   But we could also have another discussion and/or vote.
3. I also tagged this [support](/questions/tagged/support) as in any case be need somebody from the SE team to actually change this (yet [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) felt excessive for this issue).

Comment: Except of course we decide, we mathematics educators are that interesting a species we want a site to ask just about us, us, and us again! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've split the difference.  The [tour](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tour) now reads:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about teaching mathematics.

The sidebar reads:

> Is your question about teaching mathematics?

And the [question prompt](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) is:

> What's your mathematics education topic? Be specific.

Comment: Thanks! I accept this answer to signal that is the current status, and also since I personally think it is a good solution. (If however others would want to continue the discussion and voting they should certainly feel free.)

Comment: Recently this subject came up again. See http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/399/ It was noted that just "teaching mathematics" excludes some question we might want to have. On the help-center we say "teaching mathematics or the process of learning mathematics" alrady. Would it be possible we have this formulation throughout (and especially in the box on the ask page as requested by Willie Wong)?

Answer (score 7):

I think it would be fine to replace the phrase "mathematics educators" by "teaching mathematics" in both places.

Answer (score 4):

**mathematics education**

I think that questions on this site *are* about mathematics education but the site name was specifically chosen *not* to be "math education" so stumblers-upon would realize this is not about homework help. Those sentences would make much more sense with this phrase. (Indeed, we're not asking questions about ourselves, really.)